# DNN: Registered Mark changing to Question Mark

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am having a problem with registered marks in the HTML module.  We need to use the Registered Trademark symbol (®) but some of them are being changed to question marks.  I can find no ryme or reason behind which change and which remain correct.  I have tried a number of things to fix this issue including the following:

- Using &reg; and &#174;
- using <sup>®</sup>
- copy and paste of ® in both source and non source
- and using the "insert special character" from the RTE menu

Some of the symbols remain but most revert back to question marks.  If i'm in edit mode, the questions marks change back to the registered mark.  Also sometimes the first time viewing the page not logged in or in view mode, they will look fine. But as soon as I got to edit mode or a new page then go back, they change back to question marks.  I am out of idea as to why this is happening.

You can see the page at: http://fasttracsc.twif.net/AboutFastTracSC.aspx  Anywhere you see Fasttrac? it should be Fasttrac®

Any help anyone can provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ok i have found the problem.  The Rich Text Editor has a bug ("maybe by design?") that even the source button does not show you raw HTML.  The RTE is still rendering the HTML prior to inserting into the database.  If you change the RTE to Basic Text Box and edit the HTML there, you are once again able to get a consistent ® symbol using the &reg; code.